# Does Hazelcast getAtomicLong always generate a unique value?

Tags: sequence, hazelcast, atomic-long

I want to generate sequence values starting from a certain value in Mongodb.Instead, I've generated sequence values using hazelcast AtomicLong.However, when saving mongodb data, I get a duplicate key error.What would be the reason?

Answer (score 2):

The value of an `AtomicLong` can be set by using other direct setting API such as `set`, or `compareAndSet`. One of these methods might be called at any point of your code. To generate cluster-wide sequence values, it is better to use [`IdGenerator`](https://docs.hazelcast.org//docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#idgenerator) or [`FlakeIdGenerator`](https://docs.hazelcast.org//docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#flakeidgenerator).